# Bing maps layer overlapping

Tags: bing-maps

Hi I'm using bing maps v8. I have 2 default layers with pushpins. By default only the last added layer gets displayed on map. I have made the layer1 visible using setVisible function, Still it doesn't show up on the map. Is it existing but not showing up. I'm not sure why its overlapping. Its same with many layers.

This is the code resembles somethis like this

```
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), null);
var layer1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
layer1.add(pushpin);
map.layers.insert(layer1);

var pushpin2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), null);
var layer2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
layer2.add(pushpin2);
map.layers.insert(layer2);
```

Comment: are pushpin and pushpin2 in the exact same location? it could be possible that one is just underneath the other

Comment: Even If pushpins are in different locations the problem remains the same. The layer 2 pushpins are displayed by default.

Answer (score 0):

You pushpins are in the exact same location. Both are rendered, but the one in layer1 is completely covered by the one that is in layer2, so you can't see it.

Here is a simple code sample to test. Simply copy and paste it into the edit window here: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#addOneLayerItem+JS

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
});

var pins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(3, map.getBounds());

var layer1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
layer1.add(pins [0]);
map.layers.insert(layer1);

var layer2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
layer2.add(pins [1]);
map.layers.insert(layer2);
```

Comment: Even If pushpins are in different locations the problem remains the same. The layer 2 pushpins are displayed by default.

Comment: Nope, it works. Try the code example I just added above.

Comment: It dosen't work with my code but it seems to be working on bing map isdk. Thanks! Will check my code once for any other issue.